# How do i access objects created in .cpp from the dialog.cpp and vice verse in mfc?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

when i create a mfc app, the following 2 files are created
there a calDlg.cpp (all the clickOK etc functions)
and a cal.cpp (with its .h)(which i intend to create objects like timer and other stuff there)

just wondering how can i access the objects created in the cal.h/.cpp from the caldlg clickOk function and vice verse? thanks1

Comment: Which set of objects you need from cal.h in calDlg.cpp? The instance of CWinApp-derived class?

Answer (score 0):

In Cal.CPP

```
Cal::DisplayDialog()
{

    calDlg objDlg(this);
    objDlg.SetName("Craft"); 
    objDlg.SetAge("12");
    if(objDlg.DoModal() == ID_OK)
    {
      m_strName = onjDlg.GetName();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to include your header file cal.h in case they are already not included. That would sometimes avoid you a lot of errors that you think are not actually errors as such.